# iptables 1.4.11 on Android

Tags: android, iptables

I have downloaded the Android kernel sources from http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html

I have then started the emulator and wanted to play with iptable rules but I get this following error. Is the iptable package not fully installed? why is NAT table missing?

Initially I had started following http://randomizedsort.blogspot.de/2011/03/porting-iptables-1410-to-android.html#comment-form_8482839589527760177 to install iptables, but having seen iptablesv1.4.11.1 on the adb shell, I had abandoned the idea. Has anybody tried porting iptables on newer android kernel sources??

```
 adb shell
# su root

# iptables  -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

FIX ME! implement getprotobyname() bionic/libc/bionic/stubs.c:450
iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Please advise!

Comment: Poorly stated as the actual error is hidden below untrimmed irrelevance.  Much clearer statement at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331699/getprotobyname-error-iptables) however even that should not be posted as a question since it is well covered by a web search on the issue

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue even now with Android 4.2.  Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use protocol numbers (`-p 6`) instead of names (`-p tcp`):

`iptables  -t nat -A OUTPUT -p 6 --dport 8000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

See this answer for more info:
[getprotobyname error iptables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331699/getprotobyname-error-iptables/18385413#18385413)